# maximum of a linear function on a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to prove that any linear function which is defined on a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ attains its maximum always at one of the extreme points of the set? Thank you for the hint!

Comment: did you consider the definition of a convex function (with $\lambda$), and the fact that any non-extreme point is a convex combination of extreme points?

Comment: You need to add the requirements that your set is bounded and closed. Otherwise it might fail to possess extreme points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex function, and $f(x)$ be a linear function defined on $C$. 
Assume that the maximum is attained at one of the non-extreme points, say $y$. Then, if $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are the extreme points of $C$, we can write $y=\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i x_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i =1,\, \mu_i\geq 0\,\forall i$. 
Let $f(x_m)=\max_{1\leq i\leq k} f(x_i)$.
$f(y)=f(\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i x_i)= \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i f(x_i)\leq  \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_if(x_m)=f(x_m)$. 
The second equality follows because $f$ is linear and the third inequality follows by the definition of $f(x_m).$ This implies that $\exists$ an extreme point $x_m$ that gives better (or same) objective function value as $y$. So, we conclude that the maximum of a linear function on a convex set can be obtained at an extreme point.

Comment: This argument does not hold if the set C is not closed and bounded, which is missed in the original question.

Comment: Also, if there are uncountable number of extreme points, e.g., the edges of a circle.