# How to prove the solution of a constrained optimisation problem?

Tags: optimization, variance, numerical-optimization

Suppose you have shown that the variance of a given biochemical measurement depends on the time points you sample, namely:

$$\mbox{Var} (k) = \frac {\sigma^2} {\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2}$$

where $t_i$ are the time points and $\bar t$ is their mean, $\sigma$ is a positive constant, and $t_i \ge 0, \forall i \in [1,N]$.  Due to biochemical constraints, you need to impose $t_i \le 45$, too. Due to cost constraints, you need to impose $N \le 4$. Within the above constraints, how many, and which time points should we sample to ensure that $\mbox{Var}(k)$ is minimal?

One solution that results from numerical approaches is $N = 4, t = (0,0,45,45)$. E.g., in `R`:

```
g <- function(p) {
  4/(3*p[4]^2-2*p[3]*p[4]-2*p[2]*p[4]-2*p[1]*p[4]+3*p[3]^2-2*p[2]*p[3]-2*p[1]*p[3]+3*p[2]^2-2*p[1]*p[2]+3*p[1]^2)
}

o2 <- optim(par = c(1,5,25,40), fn = g, gr = NULL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, 4), upper = rep(45, 4), control = list(factr = 1))

print(o2)

#$par
#[1]  0  0 45 45

#$value
#[1] 0.0004938272

#$counts
#function gradient 
#       7        7 

#$convergence
#[1] 0

#$message
#[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

Do you think any formal/theoretical argument could be made to show that this is a general result, namely that the above $\mbox{Var}(k)$ is absolutely minimal when $N = 4$ and the sampled times are $(0,0,T,T)$, where $0 \le t_i \le T, \forall i \in [1,N], T > 0, N \le 4$?

Or if you could please point me to posts / literature where this topic (box-constrained nonlinear optimisation) is discussed, it would be great.

Comment: Would not you need also the constraint that the experiments should take at different times and perhaps that there should be a minimum time in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $N$, you are solving
$$\max_{t} \left\{ {\sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2} : 0 \leq t_i \leq T \right\}.$$
Since $(t_i - \bar t)^2$ is convex in $t$, the maximum occurs at an extreme point of the feasible region. So to find the optimum, you try $N=1$, $N=2$, $N=3$ and $N=4$, and for each $N$ you try the $2^N$ extreme points.

For $N=1$ the objective is $0$. For $N=2$ the objective for $(0,0)$ and $(T,T)$ is $0$, for $(0,T)$ and $(T,0)$ it is $0.5T^2$. For $N=3$ you can attain $(2/3) T^2$ while for $N=4$ you can get $T^2$.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was only used to thinking of convexity for functions of one variable. I see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) that showing convexity for a function of multiple variables involves pretty heavy stuff: "A twice differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.". I imagine this is true for the denominator of my Var(k).

Comment: @user6376297 it is indeed true for the denominator. The denominator is quadratic in $t$, so its Hessian is constant.

Comment: Yes, I was OK with the Hessian itself. I was less comfortable with 'is positive semidefinite'. I just applied the test shown in the Wikipedia [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix#Examples) to the Hessian of your function for $N=4$, i.e. I did $z^T.H.z, z = (a,b,c,d)$, and I got this scalar: $\frac{3 {{d}^{2}}-2 c d-2 b d-2 a d+3 {{c}^{2}}-2 b c-2 a c+3 {{b}^{2}}-2 a b+3 {{a}^{2}}}{2}$. I suppose by appropriate manipulation one can show that this is always $\ge 0$, maybe it's a sum of squares.

Comment: BTW I am assuming that the occurrence of the maxima at the 'extreme points' of the feasible region is a fundamental property for a convex function, not something that requires separate proof(?). I can see it for the monovariate case, like a parabola. Except when $f'(x)=0$, for an infinitesimally small $dx$, if $x$ is the lower bound then $f(x+dx) \le f(x)$, and if $x$ is the upper bound then $f(x-dx) \le f(x)$. So the bound is a local maximum. And there cannot be any relative maxima within the interval. With a function of 2 variables I'm less comfortable doing this reasoning, let alone 3 or 4.

Comment: @user6376297 it is easier to show that $H=VV^T$ for some matrix $V$. It is not a fundamental property, but known as the maximum principle. It is easy to prove, just a slight generalization of [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081669/maximum-of-a-linear-function-on-a-convex-set).

Comment: OK, thanks! Interesting proof. I also noticed that my reasoning above about the parabola is wrong. If the interval only comprised an ascending branch, then at the lower bound $f(x+dx) > f(x)$. It looks like the only thing I can say is that $f''(x) \ge 0$, i.e. $f'(x)$ is always non-decreasing, i.e. $f'(x-dx) < f'(x+dx), \forall x \in (x_L,x_U), dx>0$. But then, either when $f(x)>f(x+dx)$ or $f(x)>f(x-dx)$, it looks like the above implies that $f(x)$ is smaller than $f(x-dx)$ or $f(x+dx)$, respectively, i.e. there is always a higher point. But I may be wrong again :(